# Laravel Model Binding and HTML Editor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using a HTML editor for  fields, and having problem on printing the content on *edit* form using Model Binding and resource controller.
Since the editor accepts HTML tags, they not escaped (htmlentities way), and inserted raw.
While this might not be a problem, I need to find a way to print that text back into HTML editor with all HTML parsed, due to needed editing of the text.

This is the field that has a HTML editor attached through JS (for insert and edit):

```
{{ Form::textarea('text', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

Out of model binding way of creating CRUD,  `{{ html_entity_decode($text) }}` will do the job when outputting the text back to the editor.

Question:
Is there a way to add htmlentities() to model-bind-form? I need to print back the text containing html inside HTML editor that will parse it correctly.

P.S. using Laravel's helper `e()` doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried passing the decoded text into the form:textarea like this:

```
{{ Form::textarea('text', html_entity_decode($model->text), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```